# Tailwind Custom classes not working when I run the server next.js server. but saving the file again after re-typing the same class name it works

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have next.js project with tailwind css. And I have defined some custom classes in the tailwind css configuration. I am applying these classes by string interpolation. Although class name are being applied but it does not work. css is not compiled for these custom classes.

Following is the `tailwind.config.ts`(config) file.

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // colors containing the shades of blue and purple
        blpr: {
          "100": "#c5f3fb",
          "300": "#75e2f6",
          "500": "#8975f6",
          "700": "#1a087a",
          "900": "#0e0440",
        },
      },
      scale: {
        "-100": "-1",
      },
      animation: {
        "spin-slow": "spin 3s linear",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
module.exports = config;
```

Following is the element where I am applying the class

```
<div className={`text-${colorPrefix}-500 absolute`}></div>
```

Value of `colorPrefix` is `blpr`

But When I hardcode these class names instead of string interpolation it starts working, The interesting thing is that after I change back to string interpolation and it still works.